# Clopen sets standard topology on closed unit square?

Tags: general-topology

In the standard topology on $X=[0,1]\times [0,1]$, are there nontrivial clopen sets, i.e. Sets which are not $X$ or $\emptyset$ which are both open and closed?

I cannot imagine that this can happen.

Comment: In other words, you are asking if the closed unit square is connected? Yes. For one thing, the closed interval is connected, and the product of connected spaces is connected..

Comment: @bof: The OP is actually asking if it is NOT connected. Then, the answer is "no". Are there non trivial clopen sets? No. :-)